# How to compare attributes from multiple class instances?

Tags: java

Alright, so here's the pickle. I'm taking this course that teaches logic programming in Java. I only know a bit of JavaScript so Java is pretty much alien tech for me.

I'm doing this assignment where I need to create a conference manager app (which is console-based only). Each conference holds lectures (as many as you want). Each conference has attributes such as the conference manager's name, his telephone number, his hourly rate etc; and it's the same for the lectures. I wanted to be able to input these data with Scanner method. So this is what I did so far:

Started creating two classes:

1) a conference creator

```
import java.util.*;

public class Conference {
    String nameConference;
    String nameManagerConference;
    String telManagerConference;
    String dateStartConference;
    String dateEndConference;
    float hourlyRateManager;
    float hoursAmountConference;

    public void setConferenceData() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Conference name: ");
        this.nameConference = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Conference manager name: ");
        this.nameManagerConference = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Conference manager telephone number: ");
        this.telManagerConference = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Conference start date: ");
        this.dateStartConference = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Conference end date: ");
        this.dateEndConference = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Manager hourly rate: ");
        this.hourlyRateManager = keyboard.nextFloat();

        System.out.print("Conference amount of hours: ");
        this.hoursAmountConference = keyboard.nextFloat();

        System.out.println(this.nameManagerConference + ", manager of the conference " + "\"" + this.nameConference +"\"" + ", cost R$ " + (this.hoursAmountConference * this.hourlyRateManager));
    }
}
```

2) a lecture creator

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lectures {
    float totalCost = 0;
    String lecturesList = "Lectures list: ";
    ArrayList<Float> arrLecturesCostTotal = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> listLectures = new ArrayList<>();

    public void getLecturesTotalCost() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrLecturesCostTotal.size(); i++) {
             totalCost += arrLecturesCostTotal.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println("The total lectures cost is $ " + totalCost); 
    }

    public void getLecturesList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < listLectures.size(); i++) {
             lecturesList += "\n" + "- " + listLectures.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println(lecturesList);
    }

    public class Lecture{
        String lectureTitle;
        String lectureStartHour;
        String lecturerName;
        String lecturerTelephone;
        String lectureDescription;
        float lecturerHourlyRate;
        float lectureHoursAmount;
        float lectureCost = 0;

        public void setDataLecture() {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Lecture title: ");
            this.lectureTitle = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Lecture start time: ");
            this.lectureStartHour = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Lecturer name: ");
            this.lecturerName = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Lecturer telephone number: ");
            this.lecturerTelephone = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Lecture description: ");
            this.lectureDescription = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Lecturer hourly rate ");
            this.lecturerHourlyRate = keyboard.nextFloat();

            System.out.print("Lecture hours amount: ");
            this.lectureHoursAmount = keyboard.nextFloat();

                this.lectureCost = this.lecturerHourlyRate * this.lectureHoursAmount;
                System.out.println("The cost of the lecture " + this.lecturerName + " is $ " + this.lectureCost);

                arrLecturesCostTotal.add(this.lecturerHourlyRate * this.lectureHoursAmount);
                listLectures.add(this.lectureTitle + " by " + this.lecturerName);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are a lot of attributes to each class.

Then, I proceeded to create another class to create the objects using these setters (setConferenceData() and setDataLecture()).

```
public class Manager {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Conference conference01 = new Conference();
        Lectures lectureSet = new Lectures();

        Lectures.Lecture lecture01 = lectureSet.new Lecture();
        Lectures.Lecture lecture02 = lectureSet.new Lecture();

        conference01.setConferenceData();
        lecture01.setDataLecture();
        lecture02.setDataLecture();

        lectureSet.getLecturesList();
        lectureSet.getLecturesTotalCost();
    }
}
```

So, one of the deliverables is a comparison between the lectures' costs. I need to return the most and the least expensive lectures (their costs and their names). However, I can't figure out how to do that because I don't know how to compare instances' attributes values. Specially because they're created by inputting data in the console.

My logic is probably wrong as I'm pretty much experimenting and crossing my fingers so I don't see an error in the console, but this is all I could come up with.

Could someone assist me, please?

Comment: @user, yes, it would. But I was looking for a way to get all instances of the Lecture class and compare their costs automatically, so I wouldn't have to do this manually, you know?

Comment: @user, that sounds promising! But what type of list? An array? And how could I do that? Also, where would I insert this 'Comparator'? Sorry for all these questions. I'm kinda lost here

Comment: You can use a loop to check the costs.

Comment: @NomadMaker I'm giving it a go. I've just discovered I can create an Array of objects. I've created one and am trying to find a way to compare these attributes. Thanks!

Comment: What does an array give you that an ArrayList doesn't?

Comment: @NomadMaker sorry, that's what I meant. ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few tips here.

1. You probably should not call Scanner in you data classes. Instead call scanner in your main method and just feed the results to your classes through constructor or setters. This way you separate concerns and classes like `Conference` and `Lecture` don't need to know anything about your input method (scanner in this case).
2. Conference should contain lectures means that `List<Lecture>` should probably be field inside the class `Conference` among other fields.
3. Lecture should probably have two fields (among other stuff) `double lengthHours` and `double hourlyCost`. Then you could have a method in `Lecture`:

```
public double totalCost() {
  return hourlyCost * lengthHours;
}
```

And then you could have a method in `Conference`:

```
public double totalCost() {
  double lecturesTotal = 0.0;
  for (Lecture lecture : lectures {
    lecturesTotal += lecture.totalCost();
  }
  return lecturesTotal + //other stuff like conference managers pay;
}
```

Hope that gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your input. My first version used nested classes (Lecture was inside of Conference) but I was having a hard time manipulating the data between these two. I'll give it a go again. Do you happen to know a way I could get the most expensive and least expensive lectures (along with their names)? Thanks again!

Comment: You can use the same kind of for loop like I did in the totalCost method, but instead of calculating the sum you compare each lectures total cost to the lowest (or highest) one you have found yet. Just keep the lowest (or the highest) one in a temporary variable which you initialize before the loop and set it with a new value if current for iteration is lower than the previous lowest value (or higher depending if your looking for min or max)

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a go!

Comment: Btw. If you have a requirement that you need to change lectures or details of lectures after you have initially created them, then you can use a Map<String, Lecture> instead of List<Lecture>. The you could do something like `conference.getLectures().get(“some lecture”).setHourlyCost(newHourlyCost)`. But if you dont need that then dont worry about it.